# ansible: roles structure and variables

Tags: role, ansible

I use ansible for a while with standalone playbooks and now would like to configure role structure at my environment.
This is folder structure(example, summarised)

```
├── hosts
├── playbooks
│   ├── project1-staging.yml
│   └── project1-production.yml
├── roles
│   └── project1-compile
│       ├── files
│       │   └── project1.conf
│       ├── handlers
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── meta
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── templates
│       └── vars
│           └── main.yml
│   └── ec2-create
│       ├── handlers
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── meta
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── templates
│       └── vars
│           └── main.yml
│   └── project1-deploy
│       ├── handlers
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── meta
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── templates
│       └── vars
│           └── main.yml
├── vars.yml
```

It looks straightforward.
I would like to execute project1-staging.yml playbook to create a new staging environment for specific version, like that;
ansible-playbook project1-staging.yml -e 'version=1'

and playbook below;

```
---
- name: deploy project1 (staging) {{ version }}
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  roles:
  #- project1-compile version={{ version }}
  - { role: ec2-create, project: project1,  count:1 }
  - { role: project1-compile, version: {{ version }}  }
  - { role: project1-deploy, version: {{ version }}, target: {{last_ec2}}  }
```

There are some problem at this structure and also i don't like it.
- Is that proper way?
- how can i use result of ec2-create role, i would like to deploy codes to server which is just created and i don't know id.
- are there another method to pass parameters to roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Inventory Modules](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_inventory_modules.html). More specifically [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/add_host_module.html) module.

---

Synopsis

> Use variables to create new hosts and groups in inventory for use in
>   later plays of the same playbook. Takes variables so you can define
>   the new hosts more fully.

Examples

```
# add host to group 'just_created' with variable foo=42
- add_host: name={{ ip_from_ec2 }} groups=just_created foo=42

# add a host with a non-standard port local to your machines
- add_host: name={{ new_ip }}:{{ new_port }}

# add a host alias that we reach through a tunnel
- add_host: hostname={{ new_ip }}
            ansible_ssh_host={{ inventory_hostname }}
            ansible_ssh_port={{ new_port }}
```

Comment: Thank you. what about variables? Is that correct method to pass variables to roles?

Comment: @srknc if you don't want to specify the same variable in every single role, and unless I'm misreading something, if it's defined globally, you don't need to explicitly specify them every time. But generally, yes, that is the correct way to pass variables to roles. See http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html